# Special case of reaching definitions data flow problem

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-theory

The problem of reaching definitions is one of the most fundamental problem in data flow analysis. Given a control flow graph which contains variable definitions and uses, the problem results into calculating which variable definitions may reach a specific use.

For example consider the flow graph:

```
                    ____________
                 1:|   x <- ... |
                    ------------
                     |            \
                     |              __________
                     |           2:| x <- ... |
                     |              -----------
                     |            /
                    ____________    
                 3:|  ... <- x  |
                    ------------
```

The use of variable x in block 3 may be reached from either definitions in block 1 or block 2.

The algorithm for computing which definitions may reach a use is classic data flow problem. Using the notation from the dragon compiler book (new edition) the reaching definitions data flow problem is as follows:

Domain : Sets of definitions (e.g. {x <- .., ...})
Direction : Forward
Transfer function : fb(x) = gen(B) U (x - kill(B)) where gen(B) is the set of definitions that block B generates and kill(B) the set of definitions that block B kills
Boundary : OUT[ENTRY] = {}  i.e. no definitions flow for entry to a function
Meet operator: U(union), i.e. the definitions that flow to a block is the union of definitions out of predecessor blocks.
Equations : OUT[B] = fb(IN[B]), IN[B] = U(P in pred)OUT[P]
Initialize: OUT[B] = {}

However, not all definitions are the same. For example the definition in block 1 may never reach the use in block 3 as it may be killed by the definition in block 2. On the other hand, the definition in block 2, if executed, will preserve its value until its usage in block 3.

I want to find the reaching definitions of a usage for which there is no killing definitions on any path from the definition to the usage. My question is whether a similar data flow problem exists (maybe propagation etc.). How it can be solved in terms of data flow analysis.

I do have one possible solution to the problem but I would not want to reinvent the wheel if a solution already exists.

Comment: do you mean something like "guaranteed reaching definitions"? Because there may be cases where block 3 may directly follow block 1 (based on your diagram).

Answer (score 0):

Change the problem definition like this:

Meet operator: ∩(Intersect), i.e. the definitions that flow to a block is the intersection of definitions out of predecessor blocks.

Equations : OUT[B] = fb(IN[B]),
            IN[B] = ∩(P in pred)OUT[P]

Comment: That was my first approach. But it does not work. In the previous example two different definitions are in block 1 and block 2 respectively. Their intersection is an empty set. However we want the definition in block 2 to reach block 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the problem. It may not be the most efficient way but I believe it works. I am going to refer to the problem as the problem of preserved definitions. At first I calculate the reaching definitions. I am using the iterative data flow algorithm on sets of definitions represented by bitsets.

In order to do so I need to to compute at first the gen(B) and kill(B) of every block. These are the definitions generated and killed by each block respectively. Note here that the kill(B) is a superset of the actual kill(B) because I do not know what definitions and from what blocks are really being killed since I do not take into acount the data flow at this point.

After applying the reaching definitions I have REACH_IN(B) and REACH_OUT(B) sets for each block in the control flow graph. I know that the preserved definitions are a subset of the reaching definitions. In order to compute them I need to find out what definitions could never have been killed from the entry of the program to each block. I will call these sets no kill sets and I will provide an algorithm to compute NO_KILL_IN(B) and NO_KILL_OUT(B) for each block in the graph. Here is the algorithm in terms of data flow analysis.

Domain : Sets of definitions (e.g. {x <- .., ...})
Direction : Forward
Transfer function : fb(x) = x - (kill(B) ∩ REACH_IN(B)) where kill(B) is the set of  definitions that block B kills and REACH_IN(B) the set of definitions flowing into B.
Boundary : NO_KILL_OUT[ENTRY] = *U* (universal set) i.e. all definitions are not killed from entry of the function
Meet operator: ∩(intersection), i.e. a definition is not killed if it is not killed in any of predecessor block.
Equations : NO_KILL_OUT[B] = fb(IN[B]), NO_KILL_IN[B] = ∩(P in pred)NO_KILL_OUT[P]
Initialize: NO_KILL_OUT[B] = *U*

Note that in the tranfer function we compute the kill(B) ∩ REACH_IN(B) which is the set of actual definitions being killed in block B. If we do not use that we will be overly perssimistic. The algorith calculates which definitions could not have been killed before and after each block without taking into account if they have been generated or not. In order to compute the preserved definitions we simply preform the intersection:

PRESERVE_IN(B) = REACH_IN(B) ∩ NO_KILL_IN(B)
PRESERVE_OUT(B) = REACH_OUT(B) ∩ NO_KILL_OUT(B)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at temporal logics instead, the computation tree logic lends itself pretty to defining properties over paths in a control flow graph. Some example of data flow properties in CTL are shown in this paper:

[Proving correctness of compiler optimizations by temporal logic](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.138.2709)